# Using Primitives to solve a Complex Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

I need to calculate $\int_\Gamma ze^{z^2} dz$ where $\Gamma = \sqrt2 t + (1-t)i$ where $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

I write $$\int_\Gamma ze^{z^2} dz = [\frac{1}{2}e^{z^2}]_i^\sqrt2 = \frac{1}{2}e^2 - \frac{1}{2}e^{i^2}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. If $F'=f$ then $\oint_\gamma f=\int f(\gamma)\cdot\gamma'=\int (F\circ\gamma)'=F(\text{endpoints})$

Comment: Why do you write $i^2$ instead of $-1$?

Comment: @FShrike Thank you sir.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I didn't bother simplifying

Comment: Yes, you did! You wrote $2$ instead of $\sqrt2^2$, right?!